# How to reset User settings and delete data as if User has been just created in Windows 7 manually?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to reset user settings and delete all user specific data. 
Can i safely delete all folders (Hidden and System as well) from the User directory. 
Will they be created automatically ? 
Will it break the System ? if so then How can i safely reset User data and settings manually ?

Comment: To delete a user account: Right click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Under User Profiles click on Settings. Here you have the user accounts. Select the one you want to delete and click the Delete button. To create a new account go to Control Panel -> User Accounts.

Comment: For some reason I can not delete and recreate the account.

Comment: Probably that's the main (first created) Admin account. Try to create first another administrator account. Sign in with that new account and try to delete the old account.

Comment: Removing the profile does things like clean up files, and remove the registry hive for the user, but it doesn't delete the account.  To re-create the profile, just log back in as that user.  If you want to delete the account, you will need to go to Local Users and Groups, which is under Computer Management.